# When is admin_init Action ran?

Tags: actions

I have this function below that is called with the `admin_init` Action

```
function my_flush_rewrites() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Like this

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_flush_rewrites');
```

I am curious, when is this called?  Is this called on every page load?  Hopefully not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init):

> admin_init is triggered before any other hook when a user access the
>   admin area. This hook doesn't provide any parameters, so it can only
>   be used to callback a specified function.

So yes, it's run on every *admin* page load.

Comment: Yeah I had read that but I wasn't sure, so basically my average user won't be hammering this over and over, that is all I was afraid of, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You shouldn't put flush rules call to `admin_init` precisely as it's run everytime one loads a admin page. Instead run it when activating, deactivating a plugin, or if the plugin has settings page the when you save the new settings.

Answer (score 6):

All the  hooks are executed after the core WordPress application completes its loading process.

So initialization hooks are mainly used to initialize the process in plugins and themes.

Available init hooks in WordPress, in the order of their execution are -

1)**init ->** runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. Generally, this used by plugins to initialize their process.

2)**widgets_init ->** is used to register sidebar widgets of the application. The `register_widgetfunction` is executed within this hook.

3)**admin_init ->** is executed as the first action, when user access the admin section of WordPress. Generally, it’s used to initialize settings specific to the admin area.

`admin_init` hook runs every time admin page is rendered.

You can also look into [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for more information about activation process.

Answer (score 1):

`admin_init` is triggered when a user accesses the admin area. It is the first hook to be triggered. It can be used in cases like:

1. We want to block access to the admin panel for users that do not have the Administrator Role.
2. We want automatic redirection of users lacking the specified capability, to the homepage.
3. We want to register a new setting for use by a plugin.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What do you mean by *"It is the first hook to be triggered"* ? There are many hooks that are triggered earlier, like `muplugins_loaded`, `plugins_loaded` and `admin_menu`.